# Gears wont select on my mitsubishi space star

Tags: clutch, mitsubishi

I have a Mitsubishi space star 1834 cc petrol 2004
The mechanic said circlip on the the clutch thrust came out which resulted in not being able to select a gear and drive away 
The mechanic put the circlip back and the car was fine for literally 3 changes.....now it's happened again.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest your mechanic was correct in replacing the circlip, but either didn't get the exact right size on there and/or didn't place it correctly and it did it again. There could be a systemic problem with it where it just won't stay put. Take it back to the mechanic and tell them what the deal is and see if there's something more they can do with it.

Comment: If the shaft is damaged then replacing the clip won't last long - which means the mechanic will need to replace the shaft - be prepared for a bill...